# Is there a female equivalent of "prince" in the sense of "sovereign"?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammatical-gender

A "prince" could mean heir to the throne, but I'm speaking of "prince" in the same way that Machiavelli did: as a **ruler of a princedom**.

1) Is there a word for a female ruler of a princedom? Certainly it's not "princess", is it?

2) If not, are there any examples of a female ruler being refered to as "prince"?

Comment: Not sure about a female prince but Jadwiga was a female king of Poland.

Comment: If you'll entertain a fictional reference, there's *Princess Leia*. :)

Comment: If females can rule as queens without being called *king*, I don't see why one should object to the title *princess* in the context you describe.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: In Elizabeth R (1971) Glenda Jackson as Elizabeth I declares "I am an absolute princess" -- see page 201 of [Elizabeth I in Film and Television](https://books.google.com/books?id=50zStEopKDIC&pg=PA201&lpg=PA201&dq=I+am+an+absolute+princess,+Elizabeth+I&source=bl&ots=ZHTxd_kzWy&sig=SnDzykgz0aXrnzuFS7Oe5hIPBVI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwifxsjz4NDWAhWLblAKHR2FBcYQ6AEITDAK#v=onepage&q=I%20am%20an%20absolute%20princess%2C%20Elizabeth%20I&f=false).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your notion, that a female prince who has a rule cannot be called a princess, seems to be incorrect.

> **Some princesses are reigning monarchs of principalities**. There have been fewer instances of reigning princesses than reigning princes, as most principalities excluded women from inheriting the throne. Examples of princesses regnant have included **Constance of Antioch, princess regnant of Antioch** in the 12th century.
>   As the President of France, an office for which women are eligible, is ex-officio co-Prince of Andorra, Andorra could theoretically be ruled by a co-Princess.

[Wikipedia page for "princess"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princess)

"Princess" seems to be the correct word for the female ruler of a princedom. However, due to women historically being excluded from seats of power, there are hardly any cases where a princess has ruled over a principality without baing married to a prince.
And if there's a prince by her side, it's arguable whether the princess is assumed to be *ruling* (in the actual sense of the word), or simply married to the ruler.

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard of a "princedom" before, but according to [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/princedom) it is:

> a land ruled by a prince; principality

Taking [Monaco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monaco) as an example of a principality, it was once ruled by a woman, who was [Louise Hippolyte, Princess of Monaco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louise_Hippolyte,_Princess_of_Monaco). Granted she shared the rule with her husband, who became Prince of Monaco, but it's definitely historical precedent.

Therefore, I suggest that **Princess** would work for a female ruler of a princedom or principality.